# How to make music player continue playing when I move between pages in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.js framework and [react-player](https://cookpete.com/react-player/) component to play some music on my site. Everything is good until I navigate to the second page. Then the music player stops and when I go back to the first page, the music starts playing again.

While I want the music to not be interrupted by going to different pages and be an upstream component that I can change the music files from different pages.

What case do you suggest to this case?

Comment: Where did you use react-player in your project? app.js or your custom component?

Comment: @Antonio Next.js does not have an app.js file. I suggest it should be the "layout.js" file for example, but I don't know the correct structure exactly.

Comment: You have to put your react-player in top levels of the application when it's inside your container it will be unmounted (You can test it by logging componentWillunmount) so put react player inside your top-level js file like router i guess